# How can I turn the following CSV file into Active Directory Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was hoping to create a script and I was having trouble and where to begin?? I wanted to create AD users from a given CSV file but I am lacking on the knowledge on how to do so and this is what I have so far and would love some guidance

```
firstname,lastname,office,phone,title,accountname
zak,A,NY,123-123-123-123,Teacher,Zak.Alex


Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Domain="@abc.com"
$UserOu="OU=Users,DC=abc,DC=com" $NewUsersList=Import-CSV "D:\students.csv"
ForEach ($User in $NewUsersList)
{
$givenName=$User.givenName $sAMAccountName=$User.sAMAccountName $userPrincipalName=$User.sAMAccountName+$Domain $userPassword=$User.Password $expire=$null
New-ADUser -Name $givenName -GivenName $givenName -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a posting artifact, but the lines that have _multiple_ (assignment) statements on them must have those statements separated with `;` - alternatively, place them each on a separate line. If that doesn't help, please clarify what your problem is and where, specifically, you're stuck. Note that you don't strictly need intermediate variables, you could pass the property-access expressions such as `$User.givenName` directly to `New-ADUser`.

Comment: There are many examples to be found on how to bulk create new users taking the data from a csv file. Did you google for it or searched answers here on SO at all?

Answer (score 0):

First, use statement separators.

Second, pay attention to actual field names.
For example, if you put your "Given Name" as "firstname" in your CSV then you obviously can't reference a "givenName" attribute as the "given name" is now in $User.firstname. Powershell is case insensitive most of the time so you don't need to pay attention to "$user.firsTName" or "$User.Firstname" as both resolve to the same value.

Third, try looking at Get-Help New-AdUser -Parameter *.
Check parameter requirements ("Mandatory") and what kind of pipeline input is expected for them. If a parameter is "ValueByPropertyName" you can match the CSV name to the parameter name and can pipe the $User object into New-AdUser, adding parameters only for the rest of the values. That keeps code short and (hopefully) easier to read.

Finally, stick with mandatory parameter values at first.
The rest can come later. Also, try adding -WhatIf to New-AdUser; that will skip actually updating AD and you can try stuff until you're good and ready.